# Is there a way to stop running macros if a Power Query that refreshes in the process of running them comes up with an Expression.Error?

Tags: macros, powerquery

I hope I can explain this so it makes sense. I have a workbook in Excel that pulls data via Power Query into a table, however the URL for the  Power Query source changes, so I used the Get Named Range function and named a specific cell to use. I am a postmaster and the website URL is based on specific zip codes, essentially if you put your ZIP code in it will pull numbers for your office. I was asked to make a workbook that all you would have to do is type a ZIP code into a cell and it will pull your data. I got it to work but I want it to stop running if someone accidentally types in an incorrect zip code (the workbook is also dynamic in that you can run it for 1-15 ZIP codes, so the offices that need to run more ZIP codes run the chance of typing it incorrectly.) I had a work around (probably not the most efficient but it worked) to basically copy the top left cell in the body range of the table and paste it and if what it pasted was nothing it would warn you that way a zip code was incorrect, however I then used ThisWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = True to ignore the privacy warnings and sense then if the URL contains an non-existent ZIP code it simply will leave the data from the time it refreshed before?

Again sorry if that doesn't make sense, but I with the dynamic URLs/ZIP codes I wanted to explain more why I want a way to stop the macro if when the Power Query refreshes it comes up with Expression.Error.

Comment: If you are attempting to stop the powerquery mid-stream based on an error, then no, I don't believe you can do that .  If you are trying to stop a VBA from going to next step after it refreshes a powerquery, then why don't you just test the powerquery output before proceeding?